# Sliding UIViewcontroller to left/right

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I am using:

```
ViewController = [[ViewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerClass" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:frontViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I am trying to slide the `UIViewController` to the left, but I am not sure why it's not working. I'm even trying:

```
UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve
```

which is not working. Please suggest how can I can implement slide a `UIViewController` to the left/Right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, this presents a modal view controller over top of the current one. The default transition for this is to slide the view controller up from the bottom. There are four possible transitions as defined by the `UIModalTransitionStyle` enumeration.

Modal transitions do not support the left/right transition.

The left/right transition is the standard transition when using a `UINavigationController` and  its `pushViewController:animated:` and the various `pop...` methods.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

---

To dismiss the top view controller you do:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks maddy, what changes should i make now?

Comment: If you want a modal transition then pick one of the 4 transition types. Accept the fact that you don't get left/right as one of the choices. If your use of a modal presentation isn't really what you need/want, then use a `UINavigationController` and use `pushViewController:animated:` to add the additional view controller.